# Cast varchar to time and SUM in SQL generates Error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I try to cast time in HH:MM Format it works fine but when i insert time above 23 hours i.e `24:0` it generates error

> "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. "

Below is code

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
timeduration varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES ('05:30')
INSERT INTO mytable values ('24:0')
INSERT INTO mytable values ('04:33')

-- OUTPUT SHOULD BE 34:3 MINUTES

select CAST
(
(SUM (datepart(hh, convert (varchar, timeduration, 108))) +
(sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timeduration, 108)))/60) ) AS VARCHAR(2)
)
+ ':' +
CAST
(
sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timeduration, 108))) - 60 * (sum(datepart(mi, convert (varchar, timeduration, 108)))/60)
 as VARCHAR(2))
 from mytable
```

Comment: well i am using sql server

Comment: The `time` data type in SQL Server represents a time-of-day, **not** a duration. For this reason, it doesn't (need to) support negatives or values greater than 24 hours. This is also why it doesn't have any native support for addition (because adding two times of day together is nonsense). Just work in, say, minutes or seconds, and leave any formatting conversions to be done in another language/layer with actual support for a duration/timespan datatype.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is '24:00', Here should be '00:00' if you want it to work.
But then you have to add case expressions to you query. I suggest you to rewrite as:

```
DECLARE @mytable TABLE
    (
      timeduration VARCHAR(25)
    )

INSERT  INTO @mytable
VALUES  ( '05:30' )
INSERT  INTO @mytable
VALUES  ( '24:0' )
INSERT  INTO @mytable
VALUES  ( '04:33' );


WITH    cte
          AS ( SELECT   SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(timeduration, 1, CHARINDEX(':', timeduration) - 1) AS INT)) AS Hours ,
                        SUM(CAST(SUBSTRING(timeduration, CHARINDEX(':', timeduration) + 1, 5) AS INT)) AS Minutes
               FROM     @mytable
             )
    SELECT  CAST(Hours + Minutes / 60 AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ':' + CAST(Minutes % 60 AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS Duration
    FROM    cte
```

Output:

```
Duration
34:3
```